# App crashes soon after launch due to Abstract Method Error

Tags: java, android, firebase, crash, buildbox

I built my game via buildbox. My App kept crashing due to the error pasted below:

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.zzd(android.content.Intent)"
   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source:2)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

I fixed this error by putting the following command in AndroidManifext.xml:

```
            <service android:name=".PTPlayer">
            <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```

Now I am faced with a new crash reason:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.torsolutions.kawabachao.PTPlayer         cannot be cast to android.app.Service
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3524)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

My android level build gradle is:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        }
        dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
        }
        gradle.projectsEvaluated {
            tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
                options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
            }
                }
            }
```

and App level build gradle is:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
        signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'upload'
        keyPassword 'Hello@1986'
        storeFile file('D:/kawakey/kawauploadkey/KawaUploadKey1.jks')
        storePassword 'Hello@1986'
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.torsolutions.kawabachao"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 28
            multiDexEnabled true

            ndk {
                moduleName "player_shared"
            }
            versionName '2.1'
            versionCode 9
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        productFlavors {
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-                identity:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

What I am faced with now is the App crashing within 30 minutes of launch. At times it doesn't crash for a few minutes but usually it crashes within the first minute. This has lead to a significant amount of uninstalls.

Would be grateful if someone can help. I have tried the solutions on the forum so far but no solutions yet.

Comment: check this to get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550428/android-app-crashes-when-onesignal-push-notifications-are-sent

Comment: That nearly always means that you have a mismatch in dependency versions somewhere, as Android is expecting you to have to implement some method that an older (or newer) version does not require.